# Why do some apps allow me to play sounds along other apps, and some apps don't, and can I control this?

Tags: audio

**The user:** I like to play both white noise, such as brown noise or rainfall or other ambient sounds, at the same time as low key ambient music. It helps me concentrate when I work.

**The goal:** I want to play music from one app, such as [Digitally Imported Radio](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.audioaddict.di&hl=en) while I simultaneously play brown noise with an app like [Chroma Doze](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.pmarks.chromadoze&hl=en&rdid=net.pmarks.chromadoze).

**The problem:** The apps take control of sound output exclusively of each other, so that when I play one, the other stops playing.

**Almost solutions:** I found one app, called [Simply Noise](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=reactor.SimplyNoise&hl=en), that will play alongside other apps. However, it is not very well developed or maintained. It can't be turned off unless you go to the Application Manager in settings and force close it. At least it partially does the job, though. Most apps, won't play alongside other apps using sound, and some can't be used in the background at all.

**The ideal:** The best thing would be to find a white noise generator app that is full featured and lets me play alongside my music apps, as well as letting me set volumes independently of each other. Chroma Doze has the nice feature of letting me play with various EQ levels so that I can tweak my perfect noise.

**Another option:** Is there such a thing as an app that will allow me to mix sound from other apps, so that I can run them simultaneously and control their volumes independently? I looked for that kind of app, but only came up with apps like [App Volume Control Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.spycorp.appvolumecontrolpro), which seems to allow me independent volume setting, but does nothing to allow for simultaneous playback.

**The Question:** Why is it that sound apps are all over the map when it comes to playback? Some allow simultaneous playback, some don't, some have independent volume control, some force you to use the system volume, some won't play in the background, some will... Are there **any** options to help me play two apps at once, with independent volume control?